# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor] Hibernate Cache in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache, hibernate-cache

I am trying to hibernate cache in Spring dao layer. I get an error when I add the **ehcache** dependency.

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Error in Console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.example.application.AuthMain.main(AuthMain.java:20) ~[classes/:?]

2023-04-02 14:17  INFO   38338 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-04-02 14:17  INFO   38338 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-02 14:17 ERROR   38338 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
```

If I add the **ehcache** dependency below, the error goes away. How can I work with just **jcache** without ehcache?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to exclude the ehcache in your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

JCache ([JSR-107](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107)) is simply an *Service Provider Interface* (SPI) defining an [API](https://javadoc.io/doc/javax.cache/cache-api/latest/index.html) for caching providers (such as Ehcache or Hazelcaset, etc) that implement the SPI.

JCache by itself is not a caching provider and has no real caching functionality. You need to plugin an actual implementation, such as [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/JCache), [Ehcache](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.7/107.html), [Hazelcast](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/jcache/hazelcast-integration), etc.

AFAIK, the `hibernate-jCache` is simply and integration and adapter layer between Hibernate to use the JCache API an an implementing caching provider as a 2nd-level cache in Hibernate.

Using JCache simply enables you to plugin any compliant caching provider, of your choice, and mileage (aka capabilities) varies by caching provider. Some are simple in-memory stores while others are full-blown In-Memory Data Grids (IMDGs) complete with database-like functionality (e.g. persistence, transactions, functions, etc).

Hope this helps clarify the position if JCache here.